# Why do cookies installed in express js disappear?

Tags: node.js, express, cookies

I set cookies with the `res.cookie` function, but they disappear after the page is reloaded. Similarly, if you try to set them via the Set-Cookie header. I've never encountered this before, what's the problem?
It is launched on the localhost, token is a long line of the jwt token.

This is the code I use:

```
//res.cookie('at', token, {maxAge: 100000})
res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', `at=${token}; Max-Age=${100000}`)
```

Comment: Does your `token` string contain reserved characters like `=` or `;`? If you’re Base64-encoding it then it will - which is why Base64 should not be used with cookies.

Comment: @Dai I actually used base64. It was almost obvious, thank you very much